# If $a=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+a}}\;\;,b=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5+b}}\;\;,c=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5-c}}\;\;d=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5-d}}$. Then $abcd $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c,d$ are $4$ distinct positive real no. such that

$a=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5+a}}\;\;,b=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5+b}}\;\;,c=\sqrt{4+\sqrt{5-c}}\;\;d=\sqrt{4-\sqrt{5-d}}$.

Then $abcd = $

$\bf{My\; Try}::$ Let here we form an equation $\displaystyle x=\sqrt{4\pm \sqrt{5\pm x}},$ where $x=a,b,c,d$

$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle x^2=4\pm \sqrt{5\pm x}$

$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle \left(x^2-4\right)^2=\left(\sqrt{5\pm x}\right)^2 = (5+x)\;\;,\;\;(5-x)$

$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle x^4+16-8x^2=5+x\;\; ,\;\;  5-x$

$\Longrightarrow \displaystyle x^4-8x^2-x+11=0\;\;,x^4-8x^2+x+11=0$

Now i did not understand how can i solve it.

Help me

Thanks

Comment: Hint: there is a theorem about the product of roots and coefficients of the polynomial.

Comment: Are you looking for the product?

Comment: you were doing well eliminating the $\pm$ signs by squaring. why did you give up too early? one more step, then use Maesumi's suggestion

Comment: Thanks friends got it, $abcd = 11$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint** $a,b,-c,-d$ are the roots of the same equation.